# linux boot up screen image + progress bar

Tags: linux, boot, themes, progress-bar

I have a Linux system on which I want to have my own boot up image and a progress bar to indicate the progress.

I made my own theme and added it using plymouth-set-default-theme -R 'name-of-theme'. I have just added a .png image to the theme and it displays the image at boot up and even during shut down.

Now I want to Display a progress bar as well, How do I do it?